# Refer to Angularjs factory object within the factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, factory

Is it possible to **consistently** refer to the factory object from within an Angularjs factory? For example, I have an factory `Alerts` that is made up of an array of alerts, a `create` method & a `dismiss` method. `Alerts.create()` pushes an alert in the `Alerts.alerts` array & takes an optional parameter that auto-dismisses the array after 5 seconds. Sometimes this works fine, but `this` sometimes refers to the factory object, sometimes to the global `window` object. I've also tried setting `var self = this`, but that also only sometimes works. Code below:

```
angular.module('services.alerts', [])

.factory('Alerts', function($timeout) {
  return {

    alerts: [],

    create: function(type, msg, close) {
      var newIndex; 

      if (close == null) {
        close = true;
      }

      newIndex = this.alerts.push({
        type: type,
        msg: msg
      }) - 1;

      if (close) {
        $timeout(function() {
          this.dismiss(newIndex);
        }, 5000);
      }
    },

    dismiss: function(index) {
      this.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    }

  };
});
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the `alerts` and the accompanying functions inside the function body and then export them.

```
angular.module('services.alerts', [])
    .factory('Alerts', function($timeout) {
        var alerts = [];

        function create(type, msg, close) {
            ...
            newIndex = alerts.push(...) - 1;

            if (close) {
                $timeout(function() { dismiss(newIndex); }, 5000);
            }
        }

        function dismiss(index) {
            alerts.splice(index, 1);
        }

        return {
            alerts: alerts,
            create: create,
            dismiss: dismiss
        };
    });
```